# SQLCommand doesn't return anything

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to execute parameterized SQLCommand, which should return 1 value. Instead, it return an empty set, no exception is thrown, the program just keeps going.

This is the query:

```
SELECT SUM(s.cost) AS cost
FROM Spending s JOIN Date d ON s.dateID = d.dateID 
    JOIN [Service category] sc ON s.[service categoryID] = sc.[service categoryID]
WHERE sc.category1 = 'Phone' AND s.personID = @person
    AND d.month = @month AND d.year = @year
```

C# code is as follows:

```
        SqlCommand commandSelect = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        foreach (string[] p in pars)
        {
            commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + p[0], p[2]);
        }
        SqlDataReader res = commandSelect.ExecuteReader();
```

where there are 3 parameters passes and when I check SQLcommand in the debugger, they are passed correctly. @person is a string and the other two are integers.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
I probably should also add the stucture of pars array:

```
pars[0][0] = "person"
pars[0][2] = "'IDString here'"
pars[1][0] = "month"
pars[1][2] = "2"
pars[2][0] = "year"
pars[2][2] = "2012"
```

Comment: May be the string case is different than the one provided in the query

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line where you invoke `ExecuteReader` take the command text, run it through SSMS. Do you get any results when you run such query through SSMS?

Comment: The command text is the same as query. Is there another property which substitutes parameter names with the actual values?

Comment: For a start, your ID string shouldn't have the `'` around it.  Although it would be better to pass parameters of the correct data type, removing them will at least make it work. ie: `pars[0][2] = "IDString here" `

Comment: Removing the quotes did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like the problem was that addWithValue() casts strings to NVARCHAR, which I believe caused trouble in WHERE clause, because my field was of VARCHAR type. Explicit typecasting solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Are you actually calling `Read()` on the DataReader

```
while (res.Read())
{
    // something with res[x] field values here
}
```

See MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.100).aspx

Either that, or your query doesn't have any results.

From your edit, your parameter values "should" (based on your current design, as opposed to best practices) be

```
pars[0][2] = "IDString here"
```

Comment: thats not the problem, the problem is that when I check sqlcommand after execution with the debugger, the Results View shows nothing. I might also add that the query does return values if executed with same parameters in SSMS.

Comment: @kyooryu please define what you mean by "check sqlcommand after execution" - the command *never* contains  data. Where are you looking for data?

Comment: I meant Result view properties of SQLDataReder res, sorry about that.

Comment: @kyooryu and again, a reader is a *pipe*, not a *bucket* - it never really "contains" data; you need to consume it via `Read` (as shown here), or by feeding it to something else (for example a `DataTable`)

Comment: The same happens when I append FOR XML AUTO to the query and try to dump it into xmlReader. The attribute count property is 0 and the is nothing there as well, so I still think the problem lies elsewhere.